# In Acumatica how do I save the branch location at the top of the page to a field

Tags: branch, acumatica

I want to have the system put the branch (red arrow) in the field (purple arrow) when I create a new record.  I know that the red arrow is the BranchCD field but I cannot find where to grab the selected BranchCD when I am looking through any of the code. It seems like this field is hidden somewhere.  Can you help me out and point me in the right direction to look?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little complicated, but surely doable with couple static methods from the **PX.Data.PXAccess** class:

```
public string GetBranchName()
{
    var branchID = PXAccess.GetBranchID();
    if (branchID != null)
    {
        var userName = PXAccess.GetUserName();
        var branchInfo = PXAccess.GetBranches(userName).FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == branchID);

        return branchInfo.Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```